# How to add a NuGet package programmatically

Tags: .net, package, nuget

I hope to add the required dependencies to the target project by calling some functions, so what should I do?

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Can you please explain the context? When and why do you want it? Are you building your project programmatically?

Comment: I wish to use roslyn to statically analyze .NET projects as none of the projects have the dependencies they need installed. So I need to build these projects programmatically.

Comment: Can you please add more details? What would the pipeline, maybe a [mre]?